# ncat: piping multiline request breaks HTTP

Tags: bash, http, netcat

I just started using ncat, and playing around with simple HTTP requests, I came across the following:

Starting ncat and typing a two-line get request works fine:

```
$ ncat 192.168.56.20 80                                                        
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.56.20

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If however the request gets echoed to ncat, it apparently breaks somewhere:

```
$ echo 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: 192.168.56.20' | ncat 192.168.56.20 80
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I don't get it.

Comment: `echo` doesn't interpret `\n` as newline. Use `printf` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\n` in the string is sent literally. Use `echo -e` to enable interpretation of backslash escapes. Also, [the newline sequence for HTTP 1.1 is `\r\n` (CRLF).](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3) And the header section ends with an additional end-of-line.

Try:

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.56.20\r\n\r\n' | ncat 192.168.56.20 80
```

Alternatively, [the ncat has the option](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ncat.1.html) to convert new lines to CRLF:

```
-C, --crlf                 Use CRLF for EOL sequence
```

Hence, you can write:

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: 192.168.56.20\n\n' | ncat -C 192.168.56.20 80
```

and you should get the same result.

Comment: Yes! I didn't know that (but could have easily figured it out from the man pages, where it says that escaping is disabled by default). Thanks!
Unfortunately, it doesn't help with the ncat request, which still results in a 400 error.

Comment: @TonySoprano I updated the answer, should work now.

Comment: That did it. Great! Thanks.